# find() equality operator overload

Tags: c++

What is a clean way to implement a custom find() function? For instance I want my operator== to work for find for class X, matching for values of a variable close to existing values.

```
class X{
public:


  double _a;
  double _b;
  double _c;

X(double a, double b, double c){
   _a = a;
   _b = b;
   _c = c;
 }

  bool operator==(const X& other) const
  { 
      if(fabs(other._a - _a) < 0.02) return true;       
      return false;
  }


};

typedef X* ptrX;

std::vector<ptrX> vec;
ptrX t1 = new X(1,2,3);
vec.push_back(t1);
ptrX t = new X(1.01,2,3); 

bool b = (find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),t) == vec.end()); //b should be false
```

Comment: _Why_ are you using pointers?  That appears completely unneeded for this question

Comment: Also, [That function already exists, with a demo implementation online](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Comment: Other than the fact it'd be confused by the fact that you're using pointers instead of values

Comment: @MooingDuck A (much) bigger object and memory constraints are involved. The code is a sample to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your find function compares pointers rather than their data. If you have a C++11-compatible compiler, you should instead be able to do this:

```
bool b = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
    [&]( const ptrX& p ){ return *t == *p; }
) == vec.end();
```

Or in a non-C++11 environment:

```
bool b = std::find_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), your_deref_equal ) == vec.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equality operator is fine (except that it is not an equivalence, but you want it that way). However, your problem is that you store pointers, not objects in the vector, and therefore, you don't use your comparison operator at all (the `find` would, if anything, compare pointers for equality).

You can fix it by

- either storing objects directly in the vector, that is, change your snippet to

  ```
  std::vector<X> vec;
  X t1 =  X(1,2,3);
  vec.push_back(t1);
  X t =  X(1.01,2,3); 
  bool b = (find(vec.begin(),vec.end(),t) == vec.end())
  ```

  that would be easy, and would work, but may not be acceptable in some cases (if you want the *same* object to be twice in the vector). In that case, you can
- use [Boost Ponter Container Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html) `ptr_vector` as your vector, which provides clearer interface for containers of pointers, or
- provide custom comparator to the STL algorithms, see the other answer.

Comment: [compiles fine](http://ideone.com/dyV8i)  (Though it shouldn't as he didn't qualify `find`...)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Ah, yes, I overlooked the fact that `t` was a pointer as well. About the non-qualification, I believe he got lucky and `find` was found by Koenig lookup from the type of the iterator.